# Подсказки типов. В каких случаях могут пригодиться Generic?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Добрых суток, статические языки не изучал, поэтому, видимо, есть пробелы в этой области.

Для чего нужны `typing.Generic`? В каких случаях их надо использовать? Каким образом? Какие сложности решают?

Comment: [документация явно говорит зачем этот класс (одно короткое предложение) и пример кода показывает](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic)

Answer (score 1):

`typing.Generic` нужен, чтоб можно было реализовать подсказки типа вида `List[str];.

Основываясь на официальной [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic)

1. Предположим, у вас есть класс. Вы можете его отнаследовать от Generic

```py
class Mapping(Generic[KT, VT]):
    def __getitem__(self, key: KT) -> VT:
        ...
        # Etc.
```

2. Теперь вы сможете использовать подсказки типа для этого класса

```py
X = TypeVar('X')
Y = TypeVar('Y')

def lookup_name(mapping: Mapping[X, Y], key: X, default: Y) -> Y:
    try:
        return mapping[key]
    except KeyError:
        return default
```

Подробнее, зачем вам могут быть полезны подсказки типа - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1070997/%d0%94%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-typing/1071002#1071002)