# Для чего нужны typing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Зачем нужны typing? Не ясно, какую роль они выполняют, так как интерпретатор их игнорирует. Было бы полезно, если бы он ругался при несоблюдении типов.

Comment: *"Было бы полезно, если бы он ругался при несоблюдении типов."* - здравая мысль, вам явно стоить попробовать Ada83 или другой компилируемый язык со строгой статической типизацией.

Comment: Python это интерпретируемый язык. Никакого компилятора в нём нет. Типизация нужна для статических анализаторов кода, которые на основании типа подскажут, какие у этого типа есть методы, например.

Comment: Они активно используются сторонними решениями (mypy, cython, pydantic)

Comment: Подсказки для других программистов) Это довольно удобно когда ты видишь какой тип данных функция/метод принимает..

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1051841/%d0%94%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-varint-1-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5-3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Официальная имплементация Python (CPython) не является компилятором. Это интерпритатор. Соответственно, ошибки "уровня компилятора" в Python невозможны при использовании официальной имплементации.

Изначальная цель typing - "подсказывать" ожидаемый тип переменной (подробнее https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). Хоть "из коробки" это не приводит к ошибкам при запуске скрипта, такие подсказки бывают очень полезны:

- Такие IDE как Pycharm работают значительно лучше при использовании type hinting, приближаясь по уровню удобства к IDEA. Подсказки, инспекции кода - все начинает работать значительно лучше
- Существуют сторонние решения статического анализа кода, которые осуществляют проверку типов (например: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html)
- По не подтвержденной информации, использование type hints может незначительно улучшить производительность кода в CPython (https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#would-type-annotations-help-pypy-s-performance)
- Type hints используются альтернативными имплементациями, такими как Cython (http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/pure.html#static-typing)