# Что такое дженерики в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Что такое дженерик в Python и зачем он может понадобиться? Какую проблему они призваны решать?

Периодически их упоминания встречаю на Хабре и как я понимаю, они существуют в том числе в Python. Что такое generic-типы и зачем они нужны, мне не ясно.

Пример такого упоминания [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/lamoda/blog/435988/)

Comment: Что такое дженерик? Приведите пример.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов я дополнил вопрос

Comment: Англицизм для [обобщённых типов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). В Python не нужны, как и весь type hinting.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Подсказки типов. В каких случаях могут пригодиться Generic?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/666198)