# Список в объявлении наследования класса

Tags: python

Увидел в коде библиотеки непонятный код. Объявляется класс FastAPiUsers. Почему внутри Generic с квадратными скобками?  Я из того что учил про наследование знаю, что имя класса должно тут быть, но почему квадратные скобки явно указывающие на список? Помогите разобраться почему так? Что это ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Подсказки типов. В каких случаях могут пригодиться Generic?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/666198)

Comment: [Использование дженериков в Python](https://hangops.ru/articles/python/using_generics.html)

Comment: Дело не в генерике, а в том почему квадратные скобки стоят в наследовании

Comment: Потому что это не наследование, а дженерик

Comment: спасибо, ознакомлюсь

Comment: Впрочем, технически это всё равно получится наследование от класса Generic, но квадратные скобки не имеют никакого отношения к списку — так как слева стоит выражение (в данном случае `Generic`), то теперь квадратные скобки означают не список, а «получение значения из элемента по индексу» — но здесь эта операция используется для создания дженерика

Comment: Это какая та тема из аннотации типов, или совершенно отдельная ветвь?

Comment: Из аннотаций типов. А `models.UP` и `models.ID` — это скорее всего какие-то TypeVar'ы

Comment: спасибо за помощь)